# Illegal Assignment List to List - Custom Class in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, compile-error

In an apex class and test class I have a custom class that I use to compile custom attachment result records.

```
public class attachmentResult{ 
      public string name {get;set;}
      public string type {get;set;}
      public string id {get;set;}
      public string url {get;set;}
      public string objType {get;set;}
}
```

This list is populated by another method within this apex class that queries attachments.

In my test method I am compiling a list of this inner class:

```
@isTest static void myTestMethod() {

List<attachmentResult> responseAttachments = new List<attachmentResult>();

Attachment testAttachment = [select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment where ParentId = :testCase.Id];

        attachmentResult aResult = new attachmentResult();     
        aResult.Id = testAttachment.Id;
        aResult.type = testAttachment.ContentType;
        aResult.Name = testAttachment.Name;
        aResult.objType = 'Form';
        responseAttachments.add(aResult);

    myApexController myController= new myApexController();
    myController.responseAttachments = responseAttachments; 

}
```

In my apex class (myApexController) responseAttachments is a public list:

```
public list<attachmentResult> responseAttachments {get;set;}
```

Upon trying to save the setting of the list in the apex class with the list I'm generating in my test class, I am getting an `Illegal Assignment from List to List` error.

Comment: Please share the code where you have declared `myController`

Comment: How is `myController.responseAttachments` declared?

Comment: @S.B. You will need to provide the snippet from `myApexController` and the declaration of `responseAttachments` variable in that class.

Comment: The important bit of your description is missing - as Jayant said - you need to show how the controller is structured and the "responseAttachments" value declared.

Comment: Is `AttachmentResult` a custom class? Have you defined it as an inner class or is it top level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top level class, you can find it in your list of `Apex Classes`. These top level classes can have inner classes like so:

```
public class MyController // top level class
{
    public class MyInnerClass { } // inner class
    public List<MyInnerClass> attribute;
}
```

If you declare an identically named inner class in your test, *it is still a different type*.

```
@IsTest
class MyTest
{
    public class MyInnerClass { } // not the same type
    @IsTest static void brokenDemo()
    {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.attribute = new List<MyInnerClass>();
        // will fail because of type mismatch
    }
    @IsTest static void workingDemo()
    {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.attribute = new List<MyController.MyInnerClass>();
        // will succeed because types match
    }
}
```

Within your test, there are two similar but different types: `MyTest.MyInnerClass` and `MyController.MyInnerClass`. They are not compatible. If you reference just `MyInnerClass` within `MyTest`, it will be of the former type. If you reference it within `MyController`, it will be of the latter type.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought the custom class maintained a "type", in retrospect that makes sense. The terminology clarifications were also beneficial.

Comment: It is a strongly typed language. Every variable has a type, and the declared and assigned types must always match.